# Wpf Show\Hide title bar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am using this code to show and hide the title bar and remove the taskbar:

```
    public void EnterFullScreenMode()
    {
        this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;

        IsFullScreen = true;
    }

    public void ExitFullScreenMode()
    {
        this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;

        IsFullScreen = false;
    }
```

The show\Hide of the task bar is working perfect and also the hide of the title bar, but the show of the title bar is not working, and what i want to exit "Full screen" mode the title bar is hidden.

Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: have you tried switching the order of the statements in `ExitFullScreenMode()`?

Comment: Yes, it's still not working

Comment: What you have should work, have you stepped through the code and/or is there anything that could be conflicting this?

Comment: Copy pasted your code and it works fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this style and it works; as you already have a property for full screen mode, using style will be better and suits MVVM too -

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="SingleBorderWindow" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFullScreen}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized" />
                <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```